# Module loading in Angular Server Side Rendering show Error "Can't find module"

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have implemented SSR in my existing Angular 7 application. In main app component, I am loading a home module like so:

```
 {
  path: '',
  loadChildren: 'app/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule',
  pathMatch: 'full'
 }
```

When I run it through SSR and refresh the page on browser, it loads module on browser. But in terminal it shows an error `Cannot find module 'app/modules/home/home.module.ngfactory'`

If I run app using client Side Rendering, There is no such error.

Can any body let me know what's the issue?

Comment: try to `loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'`

Comment: well, there is a folder "modules" in app directory.

Comment: okay, which angular version used?

Comment: try this if you use angular 8 or 9 `loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)` //Lazy load Home module